# Variable substitution in .env file for docker run --env-file

Tags: docker

I have an env file like following

examples.env

```
A="/path1"
B="/path2":$A
```

Now, I am running docker using following command
`docker run --env-file=examples.env`

This variable $A is not being substituted for value "/path" for variable $B

It becomes `"/path2":$A`

How can we have $B as `/path2:/path1` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference another environment variable inside an env file used by .devcontainer running inside a Visual Studio Code docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361763/how-to-reference-another-environment-variable-inside-an-env-file-used-by-devcon)

Comment: That is for docker-compose, it does have that feature. I cannot use docker-compose, we are tied to docker run at a moment.

Comment: If you read the answer *carefully* you'd know that what you want to do is not possible with Docker and that `One potential workaround would be to move this assignment from your env file to your Dockerfile or docker-compose. `

Comment: Yes, we have a backup plan to make workaround in the script which calls docker, or to put it in Dockerfile. Just trying our luck to see if anybody have any idea. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Write in this way :
A="/path1"
B="/path2":"$A"